# How to run task in a task (I need to do two operations asynhronously) in WPF, when one task is done, start another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous, task

I'm importing some items from a database and usually there are roughly 20,000 articles so I have separated that into a new task.

After I receive items from the MSSQL DB I want to fill another list asynchronously with the items, because that list is later used as source to my datagrid, that means I want my datagrid updated all the time because I want to see imported articles.

Here is my code:

```
// In my application I need to perform two task like Import a lot of articles from database, and fill global available list,
// that will be used later on some other window when windows open, reason of that is I want to have list ready because I'm 
// searching articles in memory list and I want them ready in my app

// This is an event that triggers everything, ImportArticles & Fill my global list with articles:

private void btnImportArticles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
       return;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        ImportDataFromServer()) // Import articles & groups from database
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // Start new task to update some list (BUT AFTER INSERT FROM MSSQL is done) which is Global available so call PrepareArticles() method which should Async store articles in case there is many of them.
                task.ContinueWith(task2 => {
                    PrepareArticles(); // But app freezes as hell
                }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

So basically idea in this btnImportArticles_Click is after articles and groups are imported, lets call method PrepareArticles which should fill Global list with newly imported articles, so my code goes on:

```
private void ImportDataFromServer()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        ImportGroups();
        ImportArticles();
    }
}
```

Now lets post code of `ImportGroups` and `ImportArticles` Methods that are 'going to database to get articles':

```
private void ImportArticles()
{
    List<Article> newArticles = new List<Article>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();


        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;
        }

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT T1.[Code], [Title], [Description],[Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private void ImportGroups()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId] FROM [dbo].[Groups]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                     // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId], [Title] FROM [dbo].[GroupsArticles]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 // Omitted for brevity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't want miss anything here is an definiton of `PrepareArticles` method which should be executed when I get articles from database, that method is filling Global available static list, so code is here for both of them:

```
private void PrepareArticles()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     Globals.GetArticlesReady())
         .ContinueWith(task3 =>
         {

         }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

public static void GetArticlesReady()
{
    //Get All articles from database after they are imported.
    Articles = new List<Article>();
    Articles = ArticlesController..GetAll();
}
```

Thanks guys!
Cheers

Comment: make `ImportData` and `LoadNewArticles` return a task and make them async, and don't use ` TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: Exactly what @DanielA.White said, you will need to change btnImportDataFromServer_Click to:  private async void also.

Comment: @DanielA.White Does it make any sense to create a new Task inside the continuation?

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you please post it with explanation so I might accept it as answer and other ppl might learn from that. Thanks

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks again for help!

Comment: @AndréB `ContinueWith` returns a Task.

Comment: @DavidB In example above I called LoadNewArticles();  in a ContinueWith and there in LoadNewArticles() new task was started and that caused application to freeze a lot

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Your application is freezing because you're calling long running operations in the UI thread.  Don't do that.  Do long running non-UI work in non-UI threads.

Comment: @Servy But I don't know how to apply this in this example, I never worked before with tasks, could you maybe provide an example of how this should look ? Thanks

Comment: @Roxy'Pro [You should almost exclusively use Task.Run() over StartNew()](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Most data providers already support async/await so you do not need `Task.Run` or `StartNew()`

Comment: @mm8 ? What do you think about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: You might want to read more about async/await first [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) to really gain some insights in the why and how of the answer.*

For running commands against the database asynchronously there are already Task based methods, like [ExecuteReaderAync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204836(v=vs.110).aspx) for example. In that case you do not have to use `Task.Run()`. A good read about this can be found in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming).

Based on that you can rewrite your code to take advantage of that:

```
private async void btnImportDataFromServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        return;

    await ImportProducts();
    await LoadNewArticles(); // this will only start after ImportProducts() has finished succesfully        }
}

private async Task ImportProducts()
{
    List<Products> newProducts = new List<Products>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;

        }
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT T1.[Code], [Title], [Description],[Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can so the calls to the database related methods are made using the build-in async/await pattern.

Now, lets talk about the `LoadNewArticles` method. You are not showing the full implementation but you are mentioning it will fill the list in the datagrid. You cannot do that from a non-UI thread so accessing any control in a piece of code that runs using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` will bring you into trouble. So either make it synchronous or make sure you do not call any unsafe UI related code. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls).

(And please, if you do use Control.Invoke to safely access the UI from another thread do realize there is no asynchronous work being done at that moment.)

Comment: Now I will try to implement your  solution, thanks a lot for help! In my post I make edit and provided full code, and how it goes. In fact LoadNewArticles is just filling globaly available static list, which is later on some another window available as datasource of my grid, check for edits. VOTE UP

Comment: You should also continue the pattern and open the SqlConnection using `SqlConnection.OpenAsync()`

Comment: Thanks @DavidB, missed that one!